# Missing XDM calls from xd_arbiter.php to all.js cause login to fail in Firefox

Tags: facebook, firefox, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am developing a drupal-based website where users are able to login to my site using Facebook.

Login works fine in IE8, IE9 and the latest Chrome and Safari, but not in the latest Firefox.

FB.Init() is configured to use cookies and when logging in to Facebook in e.g. chrome, then a cookie named: fbsr_ is correctly set and everything works as expected.
It is set by the Facebook SDK (all.js), which in turn receives data in a postMessage event when a user logs in.

I have de-minified all.js to debug it. In chrome and IE9 three postMessage events are raised. In firefox no XDM postMessage events are ever raised.

I have tried different Facebook accounts, different computers and I am stuck with debugging as I cannot determine exactly from where the postMessage events are/should be raised.

I have also noticed that xd_arbiter.php is not loaded at all in Firefox (using the 'net' tab of firebug) while it is loaded twice in Chrome. However, initialization of the Fb js api seems to correctly inject the iframe with xd_arbiter.php as src, into the DOM.

There are no js errors in the firebug console.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Martin Did you managed to figure this out ? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately not. After scratching my head for days and messing around with many different details of the Facebook integration, it started working. I still don't know what caused the problem and why it started working, but it has worked since.